# Does angular change detection happen in services?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm just learning about Angular change detection. What I understood is that Angular runs change detection whenever some things happen inside a component. But what about in services?

Let's say that a service uses rxJs `interval` to do something (or nothing) every second. If I understood correctly that is an asynchronous operation. so does Angular run change detection and update the current views every second?

I've seen that some libraries are using ngZone (outside) for those kind of intervals, is that a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Actually, I have mistaken change detection event with re-rendering the component. I've made some deeper research and now I can say that change detection IS triggered from services, too. It is triggered across whole application when:

1. some browser events appears (i.e. click, keyup)
2. `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` is executed
3. There is a request executed with `XMLHttpRequest`

So, according to your concerns, creators of this library were aware that `debounce` usage in service will trigger change detection. It is not necessarily connected with updating templates, but it could trigger that.

Sorry for that mistake!

**Original answer:**

No, change detection does not happen in services as they don't have any template to re-render. If you want to update component according to changes in some service, you'll need to inject that service into component and share that data i.e. with `BehaviorSubject`.

If you'll push value to behavior subject you've subscribed to in component, that'll update that view, but when it's not subscribed - it won't rerender.

For your question with `ngZone` - it depends. According to Angular documentation you can use it to improve performance of your application, but only when it isn't connected to UI changes or error handling.

Comment: Then I don't undertand the usage of ngZone.runOutsideAngular in services. For example https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts is heavily using the ngZone for intervals. Why is it doing that if change detection is not triggered?

Comment: Let's say, for the sake of example, that my library exposes a data structure to you and you put some part of that into your component's view. Then, over time I update parts of that data, but I want to control which changes might trigger change detection. I can run outside the angular zone when making those changes. This means that if you trigger change detection for some other reason, you'll get the freshest values, but I won't be bogging down your executing by triggering change detection every millisecond. Plus, not all of my code runs outside the zone, so I still ensure a good user experienc

Comment: @MrkSef so if my library service is periodically checking something (e.g. every second) but is not exposing any data to apps using it, I can safely run the interval inside the zone?

Comment: @m_bale I dived into web a little bit and I've updated my answer

Comment: AH! No. Angular doesn't know that you haven't changed a view somewhere, so it's still going to check. `interval(1000).subscribe(_ => {/*do nothing*/})` in service will still trigger change detection. The caveat is that depending on which version of angular you're running, some components might actually skip change detection. They're always optimizing and there's a sort of component tree pruning that can effectively skip change detection for some views.

Comment: @MrkSef sadly it turns out RxJS ```interval``` and ```fromEvent``` do not work with ```ngZone.runOutsideAngular``` so change detection will always trigger.. Which basically means that if I'm tracking user's mouse movement with RxJS change detection will be triggered all the time.. Not sure why it's like that, or if I should be worried about it

Comment: That's surprising. I've used them both alongside ngZone without issue in the past.

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval don't work for me. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case neither of the **setTimeout()** and **setInterval()** worked. I have a Google API which is called outside of the Angular Zone. So the Angular Detection has to get triggered explicitly otherwise it doesn't know if any value is selected or changed. Here is my solution:

All inside my **GoogleMapService**

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }
```

Then using it where the GooglePlaceAPI is called:

```
  // ... Some code

  // ... get and set googlePlace details then trigger AngularDetection
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace(); // get the PlaceResult
    this.setPlaceDetails(place, fg);

    // Invoke Angular Detection since the Google API is performed outside of the Angular Zone
    if (place) {
      this.zone.run(() => { });
    }
  });
```